# In perl script I need to cut some excessive fields in the file

Tags: perl

I am pretty new in perl and want to ask you a question:
I have a file with pipe delimiter and 32 fields in it. My client want to addsome fields, which I don't need.
I know is UNIX I would use cut command.
Is there any way in perl cut those new fields, so that the script could work with the file, like it is in old format?

Below is my code:

```
open (PRISM, "$infile") or die "Can't open $infile\n";   
while ( <PRISM> ) {   
    last if /^PRISMEXP/;   
    next if /^(\s)*$/;  # skip blank lines   
    chomp;     
    "
    /^((?:.*?\|){3}?)((?:.*?\|){5}?)((?:.*?\|){14}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){2}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)(.*?)$/;"
```

The question is, what should be done with this line?

Comment: Could you show us some example data?

Comment: 0060|9592014|A001-9592014-0060|82769|NOVARTIS PHARMA SERVICES AG        BASEL|51671|NOVARTIS AG|A+|SWITZERLAND|Guarantees Issued|12/31/2016|12/31/2016|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|29014.0967835279993469339764885601502052|0||||0|1|550.3648|32541||.32|SUIG|

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code that processes the file, which you haven't shown.

But let's imagine it does something like the follwing:

```
my @fields = split /\|/, $input_line;
```

If you just want to keep the first 32 of them, change it to

```
my @fields = (split /\|/, $input_line)[0 .. 31];
```

Comment: Could also add `splice(@fields, 32);`

Comment: Do you mean I have to open the file, read line by line, and split up to 32 fields and then put to another file, which I will work on as before?

Comment: @user2843135: Not at all.

Comment: Then I don't get it. One line will cut the whole file?

Comment: @user2843135: You have to find the line in the script that extracts the columns, and change it to throw away the unneeded ones.

Comment: while ( <PRISM> ) { last if /^PRISMEXP/; next if /^(\s)*$/; # skip blank lines chomp; #first record will be column header we need to skip this if ( $rowcount > 0 ) { /^((?:.*?\|){3}?)((?:.*?\|){5}?)((?:.*?\|){14}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){2}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)(.*?)$/;<== this one? } ++$rowcount; }

Comment: Oh my... good luck. I mean, update the question with the code in backquotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a filter that would take the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, 11th, and 16th columns, and strip out the rest, and then put it back into the pipe-delimited format:

```
cat input.inp | perl -ne 'print join( q(|), (split /[|]/)[1,3,5,7,10,15])' > outfile.out
```

Of course, you can do that with an autosplit switch, and then the array can be found in `@F`:

```
cat input.inp | perl -F'|' -ne 'print join( q(|), @F[1,3,5,7,10,15])' > outfile.out
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand the meanning

Answer (score 0):

That regex is in a string:

```
"
/^((?:.*?\|){3}?)((?:.*?\|){5}?)((?:.*?\|){14}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){2}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)((?:.*?\|){1}?)(.*?)$/;"
```

The regex isn't doing anything.  It's just a string that does nothing.

You should put `use warnings; use strict;` at the top of every program you have.  The `use warnings;` in this case would have given you the message `Useless use of a constant ("your regex") in void context at ...`